# how to override tpl module in prestashop 1.7.1.1

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.7

im trying to override the tpl of ps_categorytree module, but it didn't work
i tried to put the file under override like this:

`override/themes/laber_ethan_home5/modules/ps_categorytree/views/templates/hook/ps_categorytree.tpl`

-im using **prestashop** 1.7.1.1 and i bought a theme.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to put this in override folder, simply use the modules folder that is in the active theme. The correct way to put your tpl file is:

```
/themes/laber_ethan_home5/modules/ps_categorytree/views/templates/hook/ps_categorytree.tpl
```

Hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: yes it help thank you very much for your answer. but i have marketplace module and he haven't a folder under themes so how i can override his tpl files please!

Comment: You need to create these folders. In "/themes/laber_ethan_home5/modules/" you need to create this estructure of folders -> "/ps_categorytree/views/templates/hook/", and then create this file -> "ps_categorytree.tpl".

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add tpl from my module to theme so that my version of tpl will override the Prestashop but I found all stating that to create the same directory structure in the module that consists of theme name but theme name can change easily so did it in a different way

in my case, the file was included
form path

```
classes\pdf\HTMLTemplate.php
```

so I override it from my module

```
modules\module_name\override\classes\pdf\HTMLTemplate.php
```

and override method

```
protected function getTemplate($template_name) {
    $template = false;
    $default_template = rtrim(_PS_PDF_DIR_, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template_name . '.tpl';
    $overridden_template = _PS_ALL_THEMES_DIR_ . $this->shop->getTheme() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'pdf' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template_name . '.tpl';
    $module_template = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $template_name;
    if (file_exists($module_template)) {
        $template = $module_template;
    } else if (file_exists($overridden_template)) {
        $template = $overridden_template;
    } elseif (file_exists($default_template)) {
        $template = $default_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

See

```
$module_template = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $template_name;
```

similarly, you can do it.